# Ignore Invalid Conversion Errors, GCC

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

I've been working on a project with MinGW on Windows for a while now, and I am now trying to compile it on Mac (using GCC). I am using Qt, but that doesn't have much to do with the problem.

Why is GCC being so formal, and making me cast everything? It's ridiculous how I have to go through and cast everything that doesn't match.

For example, it would throw the error:

```
main.cpp: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
```

With this code:

```
const char *a = "a";
char *b = a;
```

Are there any flags I could pass to the GCC compiler or any preprocessor directives to tell it to ignore these? Thanks.

**Edit:** Let me rephrase. Why does that work on MinGW but not GCC, and could I get it to work on GCC?

**Edit 2:** MinGW - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFuO7.png

Comment: I certainly *hope* it doesn't! Being able to disable this sounds like a terrible idea to me. The real question is why you're getting into a situation where you even want to do this.

Comment: What would be the point of types and type qualifiers if the compiler were to just ignore them?

Comment: What you are attempting to do is evil.

Comment: *"Why does that work on MinGW but not GCC, and could I get it to work on GCC?"* -- MinGW *is* GCC.  Or rather, it is one distribution of it on windows.  You're doing something else different, because your snippet in fact *does not* compile on MinGW.

Comment: I must be doing something really stupid then...?

http://i.imgur.com/zGvf6.png

Comment: Are you compiling with the `-fpermissive` flag?  You should be able to add that same option on your mac.  But a much better idea would be to fix the errors, and make your program correct C++.

Comment: No, I am not compiling with that flag. http://i.imgur.com/h3C1L.png

Comment: That image doesn't tell me all the flags you're using.  You're using a makefile.  More flags would be specified in there.

Comment: I believe you are correct. http://i.imgur.com/WaPrT.png

Answer (score 5):

It's not that gcc is pedantic. `const char*` is a pointer to `const char`, which is a very different type from `char*`, which points to `char`. For the later you can modify the contents of the pointer, for the former you can't. Allowing this conversion to be implicit would invite seriuos bugs, since it would be trivial to modify the contents of `a` by using a non const pointer, even though the contents are supposed not to be modifiable.

Theoretically you can cast the constness away:

```
char* b = const_cast<char*>(a);
```

This tells the compiler that you know that what you are doing is unsafe, but you are taking full blame if something terrible happens (you try to modify the data of a `const char*`), since you **explicitly** told it that ignoring the constness is fine at that position. Something like that should be done sparsely and only after verifying that it is ok.

Looking it up gcc and mingw actually accept the implicit cast when compiling with `-fpermissive` (which downgrades it to a warning). However using such unsafe features is a **very bad idea**, so my advice is to stay as far as possible away from such evil temptations. Instead of lowering the error threshhold I'd rather suggest options like `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and maybe even `-pedantic` and `-Werror` to make the compiler as picky as possible. Doing so may be a a pain when programming, but can easily spare you hours of debugging (with a no warning policy or `-Werror` of course).

Not directly related to your question, but since you are using c++: Why do you need `char*` when you could use `std::string`?

Comment: Tell that to all those poor iconv users. Some compilers declare it as `iconv(..., char **src, ...)` while others use `iconv(..., const char **src, ...)`. Without testing in build system for proper declaration, there's just no way to support both of these. -_-

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to ignore this conversion because a is cont char* meaning that the value pointed by a
shouldn't change so a cast from const char* to char* is consider unsafe because b can change the value pointed by a.

Answer (score 0):

This should **not** work in any compiler.  However, some older versions of compilers, C standards and other differences may cause that error not ot be emitted (or just be a warning).  I believe GCC can be configured to allow this, but I will not look up how that is done because any further write access to that data results in undefined behaviour.  You should instead fix your code.  What is the scenario you need to use this in?